# Windows Experience Index 6.7 for Graphics vs. 3.5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows-experience-index

I have a Windows 7 PC and just got a new video card 2GB ($45) which gives me the WEI of 6.7 for graphics and gaming graphics. Up from 3.5 rating of the old 512MB card.

I don't play games or editing video but use Photoshop extensively. How is 6.7 different from 3.5 when using Photoshop? Or was I just wasting my money?
I just couldn't really tell.

Thanks.

Comment: Windows experience rating is really dumb in my opinion, and is no real indicator of how good your system is. A $45 graphics card will likely not increase your photoshop performance, unless rendering massive 3D images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WEI is a very imprecise, general way to benchmark your system. You're probably going to want to run a benchmark *specific* to photoshop with either card, such as [hardware haven's tests](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/photoshop.php) of you want an objective result. Look around for other options, of it dosen't work for you. PS does do *some* offloading to the GPU, but this is heavily dependant on what version it is, and well the size of the image and other factors.

Practically speaking though, I suspect thats a *great* price for a card of those specifications, and since you already have it, you might as well make use of it.